# Error Loading Python DLL while running a .exe scrapper made with auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python-3.x, auto-py-to-exe

Need your help once more, I made a simple web scrapper using Selenium, BeautifulSoup, Time and Request as main modules. The script runs well when executed from the Jupyter Notebook, as I needed it to be executable I use Auto-py-to-exe to made it executable. I choose the option of "one file", the other settings I left them as default. The executable runs fine in my laptop and I tested it in 2 more without issues, but in one is giving the following message:

"Error loading Python DLL

C\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI105802\python311.dll'.

Load Library: The specified module could not be found."

Any idea why is this? And how can I solve it?

I highly appreciate any input please

I searched on the web and there is a issue with Windows 7 and python 3.11 but I am using Windows 10 and 11 and there should be issues.

Comment: Are you able to run your script with just python.exe? The help post's debugging section recommends you check your script works with python.exe, you can find the post here: https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/#debugging